# FPGA elements complexity

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, logic-gates

I am confused as to the complexity of the elements shown below. What is the order of complexity of them?
NOTE- this is a Pre-lab quiz which is NOT assessed, as seen by the multiple attempts allowed.[image]

Comment: A better question is to ask what each of those 4 elements is. Complexity will become evident.

Comment: Tell us everything that you understand about the question. Try to ask a specific, narrow question rather than "give me the answer".

Comment: From my understanding a look up table is an element in the configurable logic block. While the configurable logic blocks might make up the hard core-along with other elements. I however don't understand where the macrocell comes into play with the other elements

Comment: @jim Yeah, I can see why macrocell is a bit mysterious. It's more obvious in industry when you work with FPGAs and CPLDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A configurable logic block (CLB) has the capability to make itself a lookup
  table, as well as other things. That's  why its a configurable. Logic. Block.
- A hard core is a real processor in etched in silicon , inside the FPGA; The same
  kind you might find in a standalone chip.
- CLBs make up the logic fabric in FPGAs while macrocells make up the fabric of CPLDs. Do you know the difference in functionality between a CPLD and FPGA?

Comment: I'm aware that a CPLD is less complex than a FPGA.

Comment: @jim Then you should have everything you need

Answer (score -1):

Look Up Table < CLB << Macro Cell <<< HARD Core

Lookup table is the basic element in a CLB and such CLBs are used to make a macro cell for a particular use cases.. And a Hard Core usually uses all the above elements and much more that them..